# Excel VSTO project not loading after upgrading from Office 2013 to Office 2016

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2013, vsto, office-2016

I get the below error on loading the project with VS 2013 (with Office 2016 installed)

> Cannot create the project because the application associated with this
>   project type is not installed on this computer. You must install the
>   Microsoft Office application that is associated with this project
>   type.

The C# project was originally created as Excel Workbook using VS 2013 with Office 2013 and runtime as 'Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime'.
.Net Framework has also not changed. Everything looks good to me as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx

When I looked inside the .csproj file, I found the below references to Office Dll's, Office versions and the ProjectProperties section was pointing to  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Excel.exe which does not exist after the upgrading to Office 2016.

What are all the things that i need to manually repair within the .csproj file to get the project loading?

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="stdole, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
      <Private>False</Private>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
      <Private>False</Private>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
      <Private>False</Private>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

.....

```
<ProjectProperties HostName="Workbook.xlsx" HostPackage="{3F2B7691-D1D1-402F-9370-2704A737CF60}" OfficeVersion="15.0" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="XLS" Language="CS" TemplatesPath="VSTOTemplates" DebugInfoExeName="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Excel.exe" DebugInfoCommandLine="/x &quot;[$OUTPUT]Workbook.xlsx&quot;" />
```

Comment: I have spent some time looking at similar problems, but not exactly issues related to Office 2013 to Office 2016 upgrade. But is it true that VSTO project created on a machine with Office 2013 will only work (for development) on a machine with Office 2013 ? My visual studio version has always been 'VS Premium 2013 Update 5'

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem in Visual Studio 2015, maybe this will help.

I manually edited the file .csproj outside Visual Studio, changed the attribute `OfficeVersion="15.0"` in the `ProjectProperties` element with `OfficeVersion="14.0"` (yes! Downgrade it!)

Then when I opened the solution in Visual Studio, the project was tagged with *(needs migrations)*, then when I tried to reload the project Visual Studio asked to migrate the project and then did all the work.

N.B. First ensure that you are able to create a new project "Excel 2013 and 2016 VSTO Workbook", if not try to update Excel and verify that the VSTO Add-In is enabled